# How do you consistently retrieve the path information from the query in php? (/index.php/foo/bar)

Tags: php, http, path, directory

Basically if the user requests:

```
index.php/foo/bar
```

I need "/foo/bar" and for

```
index.php
```

I need "" or "/"

I couldn't find any information on google because I don't know what this is called (path info got me the pathinfo() function)

I found PHP_SELF returns differently if there is path info than if there is no info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portion after your file name `/index.php` is called the *path info* (see [Apache’s `AcceptPathInfo` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)). You can access that information with the [`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). And if you want the full requested URL path with query, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.